# outputing form data in JSTL(One Record Only)

Tags: java, jstl, cout

What I need to do is just output one customer only, not a list of custoemrs.  The foreach will work for every custoemr entered, but I need only the customer that was just entered.  Do I use <:cout> with something for a value or how do I accomplish this?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.customers}" var="customer">
<c:out value="${customer.firstName }"/>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display only one object then there is no need of `<c:forEach>`.
you can set your object in request scope and print the values using `<c:out>`

```
<c:out value="${customer.firstName}"/>
```

assuming you are setting something like this in your controller

```
request.setAttribute("customer", customerObject);
```